# ICU regex in python

Tags: python, regex, icu

Is it possible to run ICU compatible regex in python3?
For example, the following regex is not OK with default python's regex library, but works OK on C++ ICU lib:

```
import re
re.compile("(?<=(AA|BBB)12345)")

# Result: sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

I have many such regexes written for ICU regex lib I would like to run on python. Anyone knows how to do it or how to migrate them automatically to python regex format?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use PyPi regex library. There are certainly some differences (e.g. you need to use POSIX character classes inside bracket expressions), but if you only are interested in non-fixed width lookbehinds, it will work well.

Comment: Many thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by Wiktor in the comment above works.
Reproduction:

1. Install regex library: **pip install regex**
2. Run the following in python shell:

> ```
> >>> import regex
> >>> r=regex.compile("(?<=(AA|BBB)12345)")
> >>> r.findall('AA12345')
> ['AA']
> >>> r.findall('BBB12345')
> ['BBB']
> >>> r.findall('CCC12345')
> []
> ```